# Correct way to use background image on responsive menu item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a>+7123123123132</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav .li {
  background: url(../images/phone.svg) no-repeat left center;
  background-position: left 5.9375rem center;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
}
```

Result:

[image: Phone icon goes very close to number]

If i switch to XS - phone icons overlaps the phone number, but if i go for the larger resolution, then it's ok.

Maybe i'm not using correct approach to add a menu icon?

Comment: Why should you use background-image? It is much easier and expressive if you use an `img`

Comment: I would have considered an inline element such as a `<span />` in the `a` tag and targeted that but it is somewhat opinionated and there are lots of opinions.  Note that bootstrap often shows examples with the extra tag like that.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss can you point to a bootstrap example with a tag?

Comment: Not 100% a match but https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/ and  badge https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/  and on here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37762338/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this. You can use pseudo class

```css
.phone {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.phone:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/svgs/solid/phone.svg);
  background-size: 16px 16px;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class='phone'><a>+7123123123132</a></li>
</ul>
```

[**Here is link**](https://jsfiddle.net/fnh4z9d9/1/)

Comment: using pseudo class is better than putting `<span>` inside `<a>` ?

Comment: Yea its good because it will be very easier to handle. But you can use via span also.

Comment: what you would prefer yourself pseudo or span?

Comment: In some dynamic content which will change physically i will use span or other dom element in some fixes cases icons/img/object in that case i will use pseudo

Answer (score 0):

Try using ::before

```
.nav a::before {
    content: '';
    background: url ( '../images/phone.svg');
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Was that what you wanted?